# Why does the script tag, not work in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

I am using the navbar of [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/offcanvas/) example project of Bootstrap 4.6. in my django project. Here is the code.

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict'

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function() {
    $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
  })
})
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Navbar-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/quicky/navbar.css' %}">

  <title>The</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="nav-scroller bg-white shadow-sm">
    <nav class="nav nav-underline">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            Friends
            <span class="badge badge-pill bg-light align-text-bottom">27</span>
          </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suggestions</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/quicky/navbar.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem lies in the last <script> tag where i am trying to use navbar.js which is in the static folder. In the console I get the following errors:

---

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
> at navbar.js:4
> at navbar.js:7

---

However if I write the js content of navbar.js file  directly in the html file, I get no errors.

Why does this happen?

Comment: @MisterJojo don't be like that - it was flagged correctly

Comment: Ujjwal, were you are able to perform `python manage.py collectstatic` and also ensured to change the settings.py to use `STATICFILES_DIRS` to point to your `static` folder? like [this usage](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files#:~:text=Using%20the%20collectstatic%20command%2C%20Django,in%20our%20project%20root%20directory.)

Comment: @NagarajTantri No i did'nt do that, but in the previous django projects that i made, I never use to add STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'), and still things ran perfectly, its just that it doe not work here, is this something new in the latest version of django, Thank You For Your Help.

Comment: @UjjwalSaxena when you said previously it worked, which version of Django did you use? The STATIC_ROOT has been there for long